# useForm How to set controller value outside

Tags: reactjs, typescript, controller

FYI my english skill not good sorry for inconvenience

I have this code

```
 <IonItem
                    lines="none"
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                      onSet({});
                      setMenuOpen(false);
                      setRedemptionType(item.value);
                      clearErrors('redemptionType');
                    }}
                    className={`select-body--item with-hover ${item.value === redemptionType ? 'active' : ''}`}
                  >
                    {item.label}
</IonItem>
```

when on click i want to clear Input that's related with when this item change their with change follow up to set redeemUrl to '' blank for get new value

```
  <Controller
                      control={control}
                      type="text"
                      name="redeemUrl"
                      rules={required}
                      render={({ onChange, name, value }) => (
                        <IonInput
                          className="borderInput campaign-inputs clickThrough-inputs url"
                          name={name}
                          value={value}
                          onIonChange={(e) => onChange(e.detail.value)}
 />
```

Comment: are you using `react-hook-form`? you can use `setValue` to update a form-control's value.

Comment: `setValue` is present in the object that is returned by `useForm`. Similar to how you destructure `control` from it.